# How to equal two 2d arrays together in java?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, 2d, bufferedreader

I have created some code which is shown below however when I try to make the main 2D array equal to then new 2D array content, it doesn't work. I am quite new to 2D arrays so any help would be appreciated.

```
public class Simple2dArray {

private int row= 0;
private int column= 0;
private String [][] mainArray= null;

}

public static void main(String[] args){
   Simple2dArray array= new Simple2dArray (); // (class name is Simple2dArray)
   array.create2d();   //(calls out create2d)

  // array.addStartPosition(); //(calls out addStartPosition)


}

private void create2d(){
String line;


try { 
   FileReader fr= new FileReader("data.txt");
   BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(fr);


   while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){

                ArrayList<String[]> arrayL= new ArrayList<>();
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){        
                String[] splitter= line.split(" ");
                arrayL.add(splitter);
                }//



     }

   }
   br.close();
  }catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("error");
  }


}
```

Comment: your code has compile errors. Can you please update the code?

Comment: @ErandikaHarshani I have updated the code.

Comment: @user7388968 _2dArray_ cannot be a variable name and _lists_ in line `2dArray[i] = lists.get(i);` is not defined!

Comment: @Calaf sorry about that, This was an example and I have now editted the code.

Comment: No problem! I'm working on your solution...

Comment: @user7388968 as per my understand, basically you want to copy values from `String[][] 2dArray` to `mainArray`? is that correct?

Comment: @ErandikaHarshani Yes that is correct because I have been having issues with directly reading and storing each value inside the mainArray.

Comment: @user7388968, can you try with adding `mainArray=Arrays.copyOf(dataarray, dataarray.length);` after `System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(dataarray));` this line in your `create2d` method?

Comment: @ErandikaHarshani it prints out only "[[1, S, 1, 1, 1]]"

Comment: @user7388968, sorry, `mainArray=Arrays.copyOf(dataarray, dataarray.length);` position has to be changed. I have already posted my answer. try that. :)

Comment: @user7388968 As promised, I posted my solution, which changes little of your code and does exactly what you're looking for. Try it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution.
You have confused some code lines, putting them in the while block, and forgot the doubleFor during the 2dArray population. In the following code, you can work directly on *main2dArray*.

First of all,

```
private static String [][] main2dArray= null;
```

Then, in **create2d()**, after the file reading, add all the *splitter* in *arrayL*:

```
       ArrayList<String[]> arrayL= new ArrayList<>();
       while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){        
          String[] splitter= line.split(" ");
          arrayL.add(splitter);
       }
```

Now you can copy all the values in *main2dArray*, with a double-For:

```
       main2dArray= new String[arrayL.size()][arrayL.get(0).length];
       for(int i = 0; i<main2dArray.length; i++) {
           for(int j=0; j<main2dArray[0].length;j++)
               main2dArray[i][j] = arrayL.get(i)[j];
       }
```

so, when you call **array.create2d();** (i don't have modified it), the output is:

> [[25, S, 92, 78, 2], [14, 21, 52, 2, 4], [2, 61, 11, 24, 7], [56, 45, 16, 57, 4], [32, 15, 98, 13, 6]]

with the char "S" in the right position!

To avoid misunderstanding, here is the complete code with comments:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Ciao {
    private static String [][] main2dArray= null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
      array.create2d();   //(calls out create2d)
       addStartPosition();
    }

    private static void create2d(){
        String line;    
        try { 
           FileReader fr= new FileReader("data.txt");
           BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(fr);

           ArrayList<String[]> arrayL= new ArrayList<>();
           while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){        
              String[] splitter= line.split(" ");
              arrayL.add(splitter);
           }//while

           main2dArray= new String[arrayL.size()][arrayL.get(0).length];
           for(int i = 0; i<main2dArray.length; i++) {
               for(int j=0; j<main2dArray[0].length;j++)
                   main2dArray[i][j] = arrayL.get(i)[j]; 
           }//for
           br.close();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("error");
        }//try-catch    
    }//create2d

    private static void addStartPosition() {
        main2dArray[0][1] = "S";
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(main2dArray));
    }//addStartPosition

}//class
```

PS: I set your methods as "static" and,consequently, removed the line `Simple2dArray array= new Simple2dArray ();`, but it is not necessary to do so.

---

EDIT1: I've tried your new code (you can see from how it is formatted that I have not really touched it), and it works if i add `int counter=0;` before the *try-catch* block:

---

EDIT2: you cannot use `line = br.readLine()` in the firs while, or the inner cicle will override the value of *line*. You have to use another condition, according to your plain... 
For example:

```
   boolean flag=true; //condition
   while (flag){

     switch (counter) {
        case (1):
            System.out.println ("case 1");
            break;
        case (2):
             System.out.println ("case 2");
            break;
        case (3):
              System.out.println("case 3");
            break;
        default:
            ArrayList<String[]> arrayL= new ArrayList<>();
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                //System.out.println(line);
                String[] splitter= line.split(" ");
                arrayL.add(splitter);
            }//
            mainArray= new String[arrayL.size()][arrayL.get(0).length];
            for(int i = 0; i<mainArray.length; i++) {
                for(int j=0; j<mainArray[0].length;j++)
                        mainArray[i][j] = arrayL.get(i)[j]; 
            } //for
         break;
        }//switch
       counter++;

       //for example, we can interrupt the cycle 
       flag=false; //You must set your own condition!
   }//while
```

Now your output will be:

[image: screen]

...that should be the correct one!

Comment: Yes, you can convert this _while_ in a for, but I think that the problem is not in my code... There is probably something changing in the original code where you entered my cycle. Anyway: `for(int i=0; i==0;){ if( (line = br.readLine()) != null){String[] splitter= line.split(" ");arrayL.add(splitter); }else{i=1)}`

Comment: In that way, the _for_ continue until i becomes a number != 0. The principle is the same as the _while_.

Comment: I've tested your new code on Eclipse... It works for me! I've only added `int counter=0;` before the try-catch block.

Comment: The problem is the outside _while_... If you use `line=br.readline` as condition, the first value of _line_ is overrided by the inner _while_ block condition!

Comment: so How would I be able to fix this problem. Would I need to put another condition within the 2nd while loop?

Answer (score 1):

Your Expected Output will be like this if you use Arraylist:::

```
public class Simple2dArray {
    private int row = 0;
    private int column = 0;
    private static String[][] main2dArray = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        FileReader fr = new FileReader("E:\\Projects\\JavaBasics\\src\\data.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line;

        ArrayList<String> stringArray = new ArrayList<>();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            stringArray.add(line);
        }
        main2dArray = new String[stringArray.size()][stringArray.get(0).split(" ").length];
        int lineNo =0;
        for (String inLine:stringArray)
        {
            String[] splitter = inLine.split(" ");

            for (int i=0;i<splitter.length;i++)
            {
                main2dArray[lineNo][i] = splitter[i];
            }
            lineNo++;
        }
        printArray(main2dArray);
        // I dont know why you want to replace this position. if its unintentionaly please remove.
        main2dArray[0][1]="S";
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(main2dArray));
    }

    private static void printArray(String[][] arrays) {
        for (int i =0; i<arrays.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("[");
            for (int j = 0;j<arrays[i].length;j++){
                System.out.printf(" %s ",arrays[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.printf("]");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
private void create2d() {
    String line;        

    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("data.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        ArrayList<String[]> arrayL = new ArrayList<>();
        String[][] dataarray=null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {                
            String[] splitter = line.split(" ");
            arrayL.add(splitter);

            // converts arraylist into 2d array.
            dataarray = new String[arrayL.size()][];
            for (int i = 0; i < dataarray.length; i++) {
                dataarray[i] = arrayL.get(i);
            }


        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(dataarray));
        mainArray = new String[arrayL.size()][];
        mainArray=Arrays.copyOf(dataarray, dataarray.length);   
        br.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("error");
    }

}

private void addStartPosition() {

    mainArray[0][1] = "S";

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(mainArray));

}
```